# What is the fundamental vector field associated to the left multiplication?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, differential-topology

Let $G$ be a Lie group, acts on itself by left multiplication, that is $(h,g)\mapsto h.g$, for $X\in\mathfrak{g}$, how to compute the fundamental vector field $\underline{X}$ associated to this left action?

Well, I can write it by definition:
$$\underline{X} (g)=\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right |_{t=0}(\exp tX).g$$

But when I was reading P.Boalch's paper, he indicated that the result is actually $\mathrm{Ad}_{g^{-1}}X$, where $\mathrm{Ad}_{g^{-1}}$ is the tangent map at the identity of the adjoint action $\mathrm{ad}_{g^{-1}}h=g^{-1}hg$.

I got confused since by definition:

$$\mathrm{Ad}_{g^{-1}}X= \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right |_{t=0}g^{-1}(\exp tX).g$$

They are clearly not coincided, So, why it is the case?

Comment: Can you specify what is this paper?

Comment: What you think is true. In fact, what you say he is giving is not even a vector field, but a vector in the tangent space of the identity. I guess there is something in the paper that you missunderstood

Comment: @AntonioJPan Yeah！You are right! I missed that there should be an $(L_g)_*$ acting on the $\mathrm{Ad}_{g^{-1}}$, and that makes it reasonable now, what a hilarious mistake ！

Comment: Indeed, I have just realised that your first displayed equation is incorrect. The fundamental vector field is $\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}g \cdot exp(tX)$. This way everything fits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point about the story is that for $G$ acting on itself by left multiplication, the fundamental vector field generated by $X\in\mathfrak g$ is the *right* invariant vector field $R_X$ generated by $X$. Then you can use the well known formula that $R_X(g)=L_{Ad(g^{-1})(X)}(g)$ to express its values via values via left invariant fields.